# Does convex and radially open imply open?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I want to show that a convex set $A$ is radially open iff $A\cap W$ is open in W, for every finite dimensional linear subspace.

Here the 'openness' we are talking about is from any normed space.

Help would be much appreciated.

Definition : We call a set $A$ of a vector space $V$ $\underline{\text{radially open}}$ if $\forall v \in V, x \in A$ $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x + \alpha v \in A$ for any $0 < \alpha < \lambda$.

Comment: You want to prove an if-and-only-if statement; this typically breaks down into two subproblems. Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: Your definition of radially open invokes an undefined symbol $W$. Do you mean $\forall v\in A,w\in V$? - Also, I think you mean "finite-dimensional *affine* subspace"; otherwise the open line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(2,0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry, why is your example a counter example? I mean to write A instead of W.
I am struggling with => direction.

Comment: You're right: my line segment satisfies $A\cap W$ open in $W$ for all $W$ - except $\mathbb R^2$ itself!

Comment: Is there a difference between radially open and just plain open?

Comment: Yes, there can be a difference. For instance, consider (R2∖∂B1(0))∪(0,1). But it is always true that open implies radially open. If you have a solution then even though one is posted below, I would still love to see it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

Let $A$ be a radially open convex subset of a vector space $V$ (that is, 
 if $\forall v \in V, \forall w \in A$ $\exists \lambda>0$ such that $w + \alpha v \in A$ for any $0< \alpha < \lambda$).  Let $W$ be a finite dimensional linear subspace of $V$. Let $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\subset W$ be the  vertices of a simplex $\Delta$ such that $0\in\operatorname{int}_W\Delta$. Then $0\in\operatorname{int}_W\lambda\Delta$ for each $\lambda >0$. Now let $v\in A\cap W$ be an arbitrary point. Since the set $A$ is radially open, there exists a number $\lambda>0$ such that $v+\lambda a_i\in A$ for each $i$. Since the set $A$ is convex and $\Delta=\operatorname{conv} \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$, we see that $v+\lambda\Delta\subset A$. Moreover, $v, a_1,\dots a_n\in W$ implies $v+\lambda\Delta\subset W$. Since $0 \in\operatorname{int}_W\lambda\Delta$,  $v\in v+\operatorname{int}_W\lambda\Delta\subset \operatorname{int}_W (A \cap W)$.